# Cloudflare 525 over Wordpress with HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, shared-hosting, cloudflare

I am getting a Cloudflare error 525 in my Wordpress.

I'm working on a subdomain where the domain has `https` that work fine through cloudflare but the subdomain does not.

Hosting: Godaddy
The SSL certificate is UCC bought from Godaddy.
Crypto SSL in Cloudflare: FULL
I made all the changes in Wordpress mainly following these steps: [force https pages wordpress](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/12/force-https-pages-wordpress-site/)

And all URLs are changed from `http://` to `https://`.

Can anyone help me, I'm running out of ideas and I do not know what else I should do?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow.   In the future, non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that the ssl handshake is failing on the subdomain. The subdomain might be configured differently at a web-server level, or there may be Page Rules that change the behavior

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200278659-Error-525-SSL-handshake-failed

Answer (score 1):

In case someone still get this error, here is how I fixed it.

This was driving me crazy because the site was working fine and then the error started to manifest intermittently: error page shows, then by refreshing a couple of times the site loaded but with some missing images. So it was a mess.

Tried to reach out for godaddy support but it was not very useful. They checked the files, database, open ports and even changed the propagating DNS, but still the error was persisting.

At the end I tried:

1. Disable my ssl plugin in wordpress (really simple SSL)
2. Go back to http setting
3. In cloudflare, set the SSL setting to flexible

I found out that Cloudflare takes over the writing of the https links, so the plugin was creating a redirect loop and that was causing the handshake to fail.